# Codeigniter url redirecting from address url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with codeigniter, i can't find a resolv.

How can i make a redirect by parsing into url the destinations url without interpreting the / as a separator betwen controller model etc.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/http://www.google.com/?q=test
```

what it shoud do to thake `http://www.google.com/?q=test` as a string and put it into

```
Header("Location: http://www.google.com/?q=test");
```

any ideeas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the url helper's redirect function. If you give it a full address (with http://), it will redirect to that external url. 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: Nop that is not helping me because i try to make from an extarnal source to redirect thist like a external link tracker and store into the mysql what website was accesed and what ip that is acces that link. The url helper only help is the variablie is in the file not in $_REQUEST ...

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect("controller_name/function_name");
```

this code is using **`header function in php`**

it is equivalent to`base_url() + redirect value`

Answer (score 0):

I success make that,

I used url library like has sugest **Juul**, and the code is like (in controller):

```
class url extends CI_Controller { 
    function index() {
        # the codeigniter not accept the characters after ? and i make a custom code 
        # to know where is the ? sign and then i replace http:/ whith two // 

        $url = str_replace(":/","://",str_replace('%5E','?',$this->uri->uri_string));

        #the url var will return http://www.google.com/?q=test
    }
}
```